# How to implement non-renewing subscription in my own ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am using mkstorekit 4 in my app for In-App features. It seems good in kinds of consumable, non-consumable and auto renewable subscription. But today i tried to implement non-renewing subscription with mkstorekit 4. But am not able to do that. Here any one knows how to implement non-renewing subscription and how to configure the product id's in mkstorekit 4 plist, Then please tell me.

Thanks,
loganathan

Comment: instead of editing my answer.. please add comment

Answer (score 1):

On the first run, the app registers with your server and get back a unique_token. Store it on server and client side.
Upon every purchase submit to your server the unique_token and store the association between unique_token and the purchased product.
If the user register with your service (login & pass) send also the unique_token and associate the product id to the user directly.

When you design your database keep in mind that a user can buy 2 different products on 2 different devices, register on one of them and then login on the other one.